# Warning from mongodb - "(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate..."

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

H there,

I am running node 0.10.24 and I'm trying to get all the records from a mongodb collection and once my collection goes over 1000 elements I get this error:

> node.js:375
>           throw new Error(msg);
>                 ^
>   Error: (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
>       at maxTickWarn (node.js:375:15)
>       at process.nextTick (node.js:480:9)
>       at CursorStream._next (/var/www/html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursorstream.js:76:11)
>       at CursorStream._onNextObject (/var/www/html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursorstream.js:98:8)
>       at /var/www/html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursorstream.js:78:12
>       at Cursor.nextObject (/var/www/html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:540:5)
>       at /var/www/html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursorstream.js:77:18
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

I tried 2 ways of fetching data from mongodb without success.

Version 1:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
db.collection('products', function(err, collection) {
    var first = true;

    var stream = collection.find().batchSize(10000).stream();
    var results = [];

    stream.on('data', function(item){
        results.push(item);
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        // handle the error
        console.log(err);
    }).on('close', function () {
        // the stream is closed, so complete the response with res.end();
        res.send(results);
    });
});
};
```

Version 2:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require('http'),
mongodb = require('mongodb');

var server = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});
var db = new mongodb.Db('productdb', server, {});
var client  = null

db.open(function (error, clientParam) {
    if (error) {
            db.close();
            throw error;
    }
    client = clientParam;
});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'products');

    collection.find({}, {}, function(err, cursor) {
            if(err == null){
             cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
                     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                     res.write(docs);
                     res.end();
                     //console.log(docs);
             });
            }else{
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.write('An error occurred!');
                res.end();
                throw err;
            }
    });
    }).listen(8088);
```

In version 3 when i add a stream pause and after a timeout i resume it, I will get the result that i want, but with a significant delay.

Version 3:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
db.collection('products', function(err, collection) {
    var first = true;

    var stream = collection.find().batchSize(10000).stream();
    var results = [];

    stream.on('data', function(item){
        results.push(item);
        stream.pause();

        setTimeout(function(){
            stream.resume();
        }, 1);
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        // handle the error
        console.log(err);
    }).on('close', function () {
        // the stream is closed, so complete the response with res.end();
        res.send(results);
    });

});
};
```

What is the correct way to read a lot of rows, very fast from mongodb using node.js without encountering this issue?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I have found another way that still does not work, but this time it gives me this warning after the 500th row returned:

```
[WARNING] streamRecords method is deprecated, please use stream method which is much faster
```

And the code for this is:

```
db.collection('products', function(err, collection) {

    var stream = collection.find().streamRecords();
    var results = [];

    stream.on('data', function(item){
        results.push(item);
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        // handle the error
        console.log(err);
    }).on('end', function () {
        // the stream is closed, so complete the response with res.end();
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

If I change the streamRecords() call to stream(), I am back to my initial problem in Version 1. If I leave it this way i only get the first 500 row. :|

Answer (score 2):

After 3 days of pulling my hair I decided to just do a clean install on my server and after installing all the latest and greatest:

```
    "express": "3.x",
    "mongodb": "1.3.23",
    "connect-timeout": "0.0.1"
    "npm": "1.x"
```

My previous mongodb driver for node.js version was: 1.1.8, which i think was responsible for my grief.

My version 1 works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if the same problem occurred using **each** on the cursor. So with just some slight edits to your code (obviously change up the serialization bit but just showing the placing) :

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'products');

collection.find({}, {}, function(err, cursor) {
    if(err == null){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

        cursor.each(function(err, doc){
            if (doc != null) {
                res.write(doc);
            }
        });

        res.end();
        //console.log(docs);

     }else{
         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
         res.write('An error occurred!');
         res.end();
        throw err;
     }
});
}).listen(8088);
```

Comment: Hi Neil, i get the following error for the res.write(doc); line: http.js:853
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
          ^
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:853:11)

I'll try to research it and see what's causing this.

Comment: I changed that line into: "res.write(JSON.stringify(doc));" and now i'm getting the same error again: Error: (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected.

It seems i'm stuck in this vicious circle. :(